# custom shell terminating after reading one command

Tags: c, multiprocessing, pipe, fork

I am trying to write a custom shell in C that supports multiple pipes using `fork`, `dup2` and `pipe`. My approach is for `c1 | c2 | c3` create a 2 x 2 matrix to store two pipes, fork three child processes sequentially, call `dup2` to duplicate `stdin` and `stdout` to the correct pipe then call `exec`.

The shell works fine for the following commands: `"echo foo"`, `"ls | grep something | wc"`. But for some reason when I execute a line containing only one pipe like for example `"ls | grep something"`, the shell executes this command as expected but exits without waiting to read more lines. I spent hours trying to figure out why it exists when given a line with one pipe but works fine with more than one pipe but had no luck.

Here is the code that creates the child processes and runs the commands:

```
int main()
{
    char input_line[1000];
    size_t size;
    size_t chars;

    while(fgets(input_line, sizeof(input_line), stdin))
    {
        input_line[strcspn(input_line, "\n")] = 0;
        struct PARSE_INFO* parse_info = initialize_parseInfo();
        Parse(input_line, parse_info);
        int num_commands = parse_info->num_commands;
        int num_pipes = parse_info->num_pipes;
        int pipes[num_pipes][2];
        bool piping = num_pipes > 0;

        // Piping the pipes
        for(int i = 0; i < num_pipes; i++)
            pipe(pipes[i]);

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < num_commands; i++)
        {
            struct COMMAND* command = (parse_info->commands)[i];
            int num_args = command->argnum;

            char* newargv[num_args + 2];
            create_argv(command, newargv, "/usr/bin");  

            int pid = fork();

            if(pid == 0) // Child
            {
                char* newenviron[] = { NULL };       

                if(piping)
                {
                    if(i < num_commands - 1) // Not at end of pipe so write to next pipe
                    {
                        dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    }
                    if(i > 0)                       // Not at beginning of pipe so read from previous pipe
                    {
                        dup2(pipes[i - 1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
                        close(pipes[i -1][0]);
                    }
                }
                execve(newargv[0], newargv, newenviron);
                perror("execve");
            }
            else  // Parent
            {
                int status = 0;
                wait(&status);
                close(pipes[i][1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the functions called here independently and they seem to work fine so I chose not to include them to reduce clutter. I suspect that I am not closing the pipes correctly. What's puzzling me is that, if I understand this correctly, calling `dup2` in a child process should only modify the file descriptors in that process and not affect the parent process, I am not sure why it's causing `stdin` to close in the parent process.

During my debugging efforts, I tried reading some input from `stdin` at the end of the while loop by adding this code after the else block:

```
char someinput[256];
fgets(someinput, sizeof(someinput), stdin);
printf("End of loop input: %s\n");
```

The program still terminated and did not wait to read any input. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can also try to print `someinput` value, just got an idea, if there are not some chars at `stdin`..

Comment: `someinput` contains the original line inputted to the shell using the first fgets call.

Comment: You shouldn't wait in the parent until you've launched all commands in the pipeline.  You wait on each command to complete before starting the next, but if the first process fills its output pipe buffer, it will block indefinitely, so your main program will never get to launch the second.  Granted, simple programs with minimal data flows won't have problems, but in general, that's a flawed implementation.

Comment: You should explicitly exit if `execve()` fails.  As it stands, the child process continues with the rest of the loop, leading to chaos.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the children. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: The parent also needs to close all the pipes after it has launched all the children (and before it waits for any of them).